# How to edit the highest 5 values of an array in javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a single 1d array storing a series of scores. My end goal is to have the 5 highest scores with brackets around them ( e.g. (score) ) for me to then format and output onto the display. In the case where there are duplicate scores, the first occurrences would be bracketed, up to that 5 top values.

So for example:
[9,8,10,9,6,8,6,5,4,4,3,3,6] would become [(9),(8),(10),(9),6,(8),6,5,4,4,8,3,8]

What I've tried so far is this:

```
var topvals = scores.sort((a,b) => b-a).slice(0,5);
    for(var j=0; j< scores.length; j++){
      if(topvals.length==0){
        break;
      }else if(topvals.includes(scores[j])){
        scores[j] = "(" + scores[j] + ")";
        topvals.splice(topvals.indexOf(scores[j]),1);
      }
    }
```

With the idea that topvals is an array containing the top 5 values, and I then loop through scores looking for those values, removing them each time.

What this results in is the first 5 values of scores having brackets around them.

I'm happy to go a completely different route with this, or just fix what I've done so far. Thanks in advance.

Comment: just clone scores.  scoreclone = scores.slice()

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Keep original array after JavaScript function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19169873/keep-original-array-after-javascript-function)

Comment: Unfortunately not. That post only deals with editing the array where you know where the values are.
The problem I have is what is described in the text of the post.

Comment: Should `dvals` in your example be `topvals`?   Also can you explain what error / unexpected behavior you are having?

Comment: How efficient does this need to be?  Easiest way is to just `scores.map((n,i)=>({n,i})).sort((a,b)=>b.n-a.n).slice(0,5).map(({i})=>i).forEach(i=>scores[i]=\`(${scores[i]})\`)`.  If you need O(N) for large data sets, you can do a pivot algorithm.

Comment: Your example doesn't match your description, both `8`s are surrounded by braces.  Did you only mean the first 8 to be braced?  Because you say `... the first occurrence would be bracketed`.  Also your code contains a few errors `scores[i][j]` should be `scores[j]` and it seems that `dvals` should be `topvals`.

Comment: @IanWilson Sorry, you're right on the first bit, this is coming out of a much bigger project so was trying to change some variables to make sense on their own.
No, the second 8 should be braced as well. The top 5 values are 10,9,9,8,8 so the first two 8s should be braced, but not the third.
Does that explain it better?

Comment: Yes, that makes sense now.  Funny how things can be interpreted.  But also the lists do not seem to be the same list.  The last 3 digits of the original list are `3,3,6` and the last 3 digits of the formatted list are `8,3,8`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sort with indexes attached.  Use index positions to change to desired format.  O(N log N) for the sort.

```js
scores = [9,8,10,9,6,8,6,5,4,4,3,3,6]
scores.map((n,i)=>({n,i})) // each object as n: number, i: index
  .sort((a,b)=>a.n-b.n).slice(-5) // sort, slice top 5
  .forEach(({i})=>scores[i]=`(${scores[i]})`) // add parens by indexes

console.log(scores)
```

If you have very, very large data sets and need something closer to O(N), you'll want to implement a pivot selecting algorithm.  Just sorting is simpler.

Comment: Thank you, sorting with indexes attached should work for this exactly. I had been bashing my head against the wall in one particular direction for a while so couldn't see other routes to take!

Answer (score 0):

The call to `sort()` sorts `scores` in place, which means it changes the `scores` array.  So that is why you need to clone it first, then sort, then slice.  Also you probably want to eliminate duplicates from your scores. I linked a stack overflow answer that describes how to do that. Since filter does not filter `scores` in place, but rather returns a new array, you don't need to explicitly call `slice(0)` to clone `scores`.

```
var scores = [9,8,10,9,6,8,6,5,4,4,3,3,6];

// Function from linked SO answer.
function onlyUnique(value, index, self) { 
    return self.indexOf(value) === index;
}

// Filter unique scores into copy of array, then slice the top 5.
var topvals = scores.filter(onlyUnique).sort((a,b) => b-a).slice(0,5);

for (var j=0; j< scores.length; j++) {
   if( topvals.length==0) {
        break;
   } else if(topvals.includes(scores[j])) {
        scores[j] = "(" + scores[j] + ")";
        topvals.splice(topvals.indexOf(scores[j]),1);
   }
}
```

[Get all unique values in a JavaScript array (remove duplicates)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1960473/get-all-unique-values-in-a-javascript-array-remove-duplicates)

Comment: The problem with this is that I need to keep the duplicates. The question stems from the very end of a bigger project where I just need to do some formatting before output so the data needs to be kept exactly as is.